# AMI change for EC2 instance is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In my workplace, we have a process of changing the EC2's AMI every month with the new patched private AMI.

Our internal operations team makes these patched AMI available for us as private AMI for EC2.

In our terraform script, we change the name of the AMI to the new one before executing the script via Jenkins.

However, we have noticed that after the script is executed EC2 instance is not affected by the AMI name change, we have to manually terminate each EC2 instance for the AMI change to take effect.

What I want to know is-

1. Is this a problem someone has faced before?
2. Is there a way to remove the manual termination of instance in Terraform OR is there a way in Terraform by which the changes will be taken cared of automatically?

Comment: Are these instances in autoscaling group?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, they are in the autoscaling group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instances in ASG are not being updated with the new AMI because by default, only your launch configuration (LC) or launch template (LT) are updated with the new AMI. This **does not automatically** causes an update of the instances to use the new LC/LT.

However, since not too long ago, AWS has introduce [instance refresh](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-refresh-for-ec2-auto-scaling/) to combat this specific issue. Subsequently, this functionality was added to terraform and is configured using [instance_refresh](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group#instance_refresh) block of `aws_autoscaling_group` resource.

Thus, you could setup `instance_refresh` in your `aws_autoscaling_group` and specify what **triggers it**. Usually the trigger would be changes to the associated `launch_configuration` or `launch_template`.